# Scheduler using java swing jdk 1.4

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to develop a scheduler using Java swing jdk 1.4. I have used quartz 1.5.2. jar for scheduling. But the problem I am facing here is, whenever I close the frame, scheduler also get disconnected automatically. Please suggest. Please find below my scheduler method.

```
    public void Scheduler() throws ParseException, IOException{

             JobDetail job = new JobDetail();
             job.setName(textField_2.getText());

                job.setJobClass(HelloJob.class);
                SimpleTrigger trigger=new SimpleTrigger();
                trigger.setName(textField_2_trigg.getText());
                trigger.setStartTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000));
                trigger.setRepeatCount(SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY);

                trigger.setRepeatInterval(30000);

                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(textField_path.getText()+"\\aaa.ser");
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
                oos.writeObject(job);
                oos.writeObject(trigger);

                try{
                      FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(textField_path.getText()+"\\aaa.ser");
                   ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
                 //  job = (JobDetail) ois.readObject();
                  // ois.close();
                    Scheduler scheduler = new    StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
                    scheduler.start();
                    //JobDetail job=(JobDetail) oos.
                    /*HSSFCell cellA1 = titleRow.getCell((short) 0);
                    String a1Val = cellA1.getStringCellValue();
                    HSSFCell cellA2 = titleRow.getCell((short) 1);
                    String a2Val = cellA2.getStringCellValue();*/
                    scheduler.scheduleJob(job = (JobDetail) ois.readObject(),             trigger=(SimpleTrigger) ois.readObject());

                }catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.getMessage();
                }
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Scheduled");
                        //fileOut1.close();
 }
```

Comment: whenever i close the frame, scheduler also get disconnected automatically.  == please then why isn't there an SSCCE / MCVE, code snipped talking about nothing in this context

Comment: how can i store the job and triggers using file.